# The maximum likelihood method in the irregular case

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, estimation, maximum-likelihood

The question arose what to do if the density of a random variable depends on $(\alpha-x)$ (maybe in some degree) on the interval from 0 to $\alpha$, for example. The likelihood function then turns out to depend on the product of $(\alpha-x)^n$. And when the MLE estimator is set to  $\hat\alpha=max(X_i)$, it turns out that the likelihood function is reset to zero. What about the MLE estimator in such cases?
For example, if r.v. with density
$f(x)=\left ( \frac{2\left ( \alpha -x \right )}{\alpha^2}\right ) if x\in \left [ 0;\alpha  \right ]$

or the second example in this message
The Doctor (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/165662/the-doctor), Existence of Maximum Likelihood Estimator, URL (version: 2017-10-08): [Existence of Maximum Likelihood Estimator](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2463064)

When substituting such an estimator $\hat{\mu}=X_{(1)}$, the likelihood function is equal to 0 too - one of the multipliers, where the minimum member of the sample comes across, resets it. What about this estimation then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the lileihood is

$$L(X;a)=\frac{2^n}{a^{2n}} \prod_{i=1}^n (a-x_i) [0\le x_i \le a]$$

In terms of the variable $a$, this gives the domain $a \in [\max(x_i), +\infty)$.
Inside this domain, $L(X;a)$ is differentiable. Hence, its global maximum is either a critical point inside the domain, or either lies in the extremes. But the latter is not possible, because $L(X; \max(x_i))=0$. Hence we can seek for critical points.

Using the log likelihood, deriving and equating to zero we get the following equation for the critical point(s):

$$ a =\frac{2n}{\sum \frac{1}{a-x_i}} =2\,{\rm Hm}(a-x_i) $$

where $Hm$ denotes the [harmonic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean).

This should be solved numerically (inside the domain).

Comment: thank you very much! But I don't understand how to solve it if a is both on the left side and on the right under the sum in the denominator

Comment: You can't solve that analytically. You must resort for some iterative procedure.

For example, here's an iterative calculation, for $n=3$, $x=(10,20,30)$, it gives $a=45.51$  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bFzbuPnUtnPSHTHCAmbE5Pkh6X280C8nZjfCU6ucxLE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks again! And with the minimum in the second example, about the same story?

Comment: and I wonder why the MLE estimate is so shifted towards the maximum of the sample... Exceeds 1.5 times. Well, maybe because the sample is so small...